# How do you write out an MVC Action for an elements attribute

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

How do you write out the action for an element I've tried to do

```
data-yes="@{Url.Action("DeleteAndAppend", "DepartmentsController", new { id = item.DepartmentId });}" but I always getting nothing
```

and tried this also and I'm not getting the out put of the action or path

```
data-yes="@{Html.Action("DeleteAll", new { id = item.DepartmentId });}"
```

I just want the path of the action and the controller with the id output
Does anyone know how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you should not use @{}, this syntax is used for executing code that doesn't actually output anything to the rendered view.

Simply write

```
data-yes="@Url.Action(...)"
```

The Razor engine will know that the C# code ends at the closing parenthesis.

You can also use Url.RouteUrl:

```
@Url.RouteUrl(new {controller= "Departments", action = "DeleteAndAppend", id = item.DepartmentId })
```

Answer (score 2):

Braces (`@{}`) define a *code block* and the "output" (in this case just a return value) will be discarded. Note the fact that you've had to use a semicolon after the line.

Instead, I believe you wanted:

```
data-yes="@Url.Action("DeleteAndAppend", "DepartmentsController", new { id = item.DepartmentId })"
```

*Yes, it's smart enough to figure out who the quotes belong to.*

---

You could also use parentheses `@()` if you want to be explicit:

```
data-yes="@(Url.Action("DeleteAndAppend", "DepartmentsController", new { id = item.DepartmentId }))"
```

This is particularly useful when you need to put text after a value, without a space between:

```
<p>This is your @(Model.NumberOfVisits)th visit here!</p>
```